# probelm with puppet tagmail puppetlabs module

Tags: puppet

i'm using puppet 6.14.0 and tagmail module 3.2.0 on Centos 7.

below is my config on the master:

```
[master]
dns_alt_names=*******
vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
codedir = /etc/puippetlabs/code
confdir = /etc/puppetlabs/puppet
reports = puppetdb,console,tagmail
tagmap = $confdir/tagmail.conf
```

tagmail.conf(using a local smtp server, i'm able to telnet it )

```
[transport]
reportfrom = **********
smtpserver = localhost
smtpport = 25
smtphelo = localhost

[tagmap]
all: my_email_address
```

and below is my config on one managed node

```
[main]
 certname = *********
 server = *********
 environment =uat
 runinterval = 120
[agent]
 report = true
 pluginsync = true
```

but i'm not receiving any report from tagmail.
is someone having the same problem or i'm missing something on my config ?

Comment: You need to write a Puppet class to configure the tagmail module for your directory environment. The tagmail module documentation should have the necessary information.

Comment: thanks Matt, but i'm not able to locate any kind of related information on tagmail documentation 
https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/tagmail/readme